# Only show one hidden table row at a time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I have a table where every second table row has a class name of "hideme". 
In my css file I have made .hideme { display:none}

The hidden row contains options/information about the row above it.
My goal is to use jquery to toggle the hidden row on/off when the row above is clicked.
 I have succeded at this, however the code has a flaw. I can have multiple hidden rows shown at the same time. This is not desirable. I'd like to have only a single hidden row shown at any given time , or none at all.

How should I change my jQuery code to make my table act like i want it to?

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#eventtable tr').click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").next().toggle();
});
});
```

My HTML/PHP is as follows:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        echo '
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>' . $row['event'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row['dr'] . '</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class = "hideme"> 
                    <form method="post" action="galleryHandler.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Name" value="' . $row['name'] . '" />    
                    <td><input type="password" class="input" name="password" size="25" maxlength="20"/></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Se fotosession" class="button2"/></td>
                    </form>         
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        ';

    }
```

The problem has been solved by a kind stackoverflow user. However I still have a problem because I have text fields in the hidden rows, which I didn't mention at first, and they disappear when I clikc on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#eventtable tr:even').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).next().css('display') == 'none') {
            $('#eventtable .hideme').hide();
            $(this).next().show();
        }
        else {
            $('#eventtable .hideme').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/aTN6v/

This will make the toggle behaviour work, but will close whichever one is already open before opening the one you've clicked.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm! Found out that I needed a a more recent version of jquery as well.

Comment: Ups... I have a textfield in the hidden rows. When I click in it to type in some text the hidden row disappear again. What should I do?

Comment: Just edited to add `:even` to the initial selector for the event handler, so only the normally-visible rows respond to the clicks.

Comment: (If you're wondering why it's `:even` for what are ostensibly the odd rows (1, 3, 5) it's because as per JavaScript rules it starts from 0, not 1.

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me... $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#eventtable tr:not(.hideme)').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).next().css('display') == 'none') {
            $('#eventtable .hideme').hide();
            $(this).next().toggle();
        }
        else {
            $('#eventtable .hideme').hide();
        }
    });
});

Answer (score 1):

Hide all others before:

```
$('#eventtable tr:even').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#eventtable > tbody > tr > td').click(function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").next().toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#eventtable tr').click(function() {
    var nextRow = $(this).closest("tr").next();
    $('#eventtable tr.hideme').not(nextRow).hide(); 
    nextRow.toggle();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the **HTML** in the following structure

```
<table border="1">
    <tr><td>1.a</td><td>foo</td></tr>
    <tr class="hideme"><td>1.b</td><td>foo</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2.a</td><td>bar</td></tr>
    <tr class="hideme"><td>2.b</td><td>bar</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3.a</td><td>baz</td></tr>
    <tr class="hideme"><td>3.b</td><td>baz</td></tr>
</table>
```

and with **CSS** as follows

```
.hideme { display:none; }
```

the following **JS Code** should do the trick

```
$('tr:even').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggleClass('hideme');
});
```

Check the working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5rAtZ/2/).